# Error importing C functions in python

Tags: c, python-2.7, python-import

I'm using eclipse with `PyDev`, `Python 2.7`, and have the following problem.
 
From a package, containing `.py` and `c`  modules, i have imported the `.py` modules, but not the `C` source files.

I have imported the `C Function` module (.py!) from the sg package, which includes the following line:

```
try:
    import sg._cfunc as _cfunc
except ImportError:
    import pyximport
    pyximport.install(setup_args={"include_dirs": np.get_include()},
                      reload_support=True)
    import sg._cfunc as _cfunc



ImportError: No module named _cfunc
```

However the C Source file is in .../site-packages/sg.

Moreover, this function was working beforehand, and is still working on an other computer.

I have already reinstalled Cython, but nothing happened.

Any idea? :(

Comment: "However the C Source file is in the given directory." I don't see a directory given in the code above. Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27840507/edit) with the layout of your project.

Comment: i mean it is in the site-packages/sg

Comment: Don't you need a `*.pyx` instead of a C file? Or probably both, one pointing to the other.

Comment: Actually i'm only using this package and it doesn't include any .pyx file. And it is working without it on an other computer. And pyximport would create a c file from the .pyx file, and as far as the c file is present, the exception shouldn't occure. I think the problem is with "seeing" the c files, but i don't know what to do.

Comment: I think Cython is not "seeing the C file" because there's no corresponding *pyx file. Previously, that file may have been there (and is on the other machine), or there's even a corresponding *.so file. If the C file is generated from the a .pyx file, better put the .pyx file back in the package.